# Error running decrypt script in NiFi using ExecuteStreamCommand

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a script I inherited called `decryptor` that decrypts aws files. The script lives in a directory `/opt/project_name` and when I run `./decryptor decrypt-file --filename ${filename} --private-key-file keys/prod_key.priv --public-key-file keys/prod_key.pub` on the command line, it runs without issue. However, when I attempt to run this in NiFi using `ExecuteStreamCommand` it tells me that the directory does not exist--however, I know that it does exist (and NiFi has access to it) because it's the same directory that it picks up the flow files from which then trigger the processor.

I've tried using both `${filename}` and explicitly putting the file name. The error I get back is: `ExecuteStreamCommand Failed to process session due to java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./decryptor " (in directory "/opt/project_name"): error=2, No such file or directory: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./decryptor " (in directory "/opt/project_name"): error=2, No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong in my configs that is causing this to not run? I'm really at a loss here.

[image: ExecuteStreamCommand configs]

Comment: Can you use a `LogAttribute` processor or view the data provenance to examine the `filename` attribute and ensure it's an absolute path? It's possible the filename is relative to the directory from where it was retrieved, and when running this process from NiFi, the full file path can't be constructed & located.

Comment: @Andy I added an attribute `absolutepath` that combined the absolute path with the filename in one attribute and tried it, and got the same error.

Comment: You can try using `set -x` in your script (or `-x` as a flag on the CLI invocation) to enable shell debugging. This may help you locate the issue around the file not being found. Can you find an example file that does not work when invoked by NiFi, does when invoked explicitly on the command-line, and show the output of `ls -al` from that directory at the time? Similarly, are you sure the OS user NiFi is running as has ACL access?